# Cannot install the Rubygem "Link Parser"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, linkparser

I would like to create a chatbot, and for that I want to use [Link Parser](http://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/), which is basically an engine that finds out the relations between words when looking at a sentence.

There is a [Ruby wrapper](http://deveiate.org/projects/Ruby-LinkParser) which I tried to install by using:

```
gem install linkparser
```

and also:

```
gem install linkparser -- --with-link-grammar="C:\Users\Gebruiker\Downloads\Linkparsergrammar\linkgrammar4r-0.0.3"
```

However, I keep getting the following errors:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing linkparser:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-link-grammar=C:\Users\Gebruiker\Downloads\Linkparsergrammar\linkgrammar4r-0.0.3
checking for pkg-config... no
Couldn't find your pkg-config binary
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby
        --with-link-grammar
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/linkparser-1.1.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/linkparser-1.1.3/ext/gem_make.out
```

I am on Windows Vista 32bit, and using the newest Ruby (1.9.3-p125)

Can somebody explain what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help with your problem? [problems on installing link-parser gem on snow leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113900/problems-on-installing-link-parser-gem-on-snow-leopard)

I know it's for mac but it sounds similar